Unauthorized (http 401) error with .NET 8 custom token handler
In .NET 8, I'm trying to implement a custom JWT token handler. The incoming JWT is missing the aud and iss claims. This may be incompliant with the OAuth standard (not sure), but it's something I have to deal with.
I've read about the breaking changes in .NET 8 concerning JWT token validation:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/508.
So I'm trying to implement a TokenHandler rather than a ISecurityTokenValidator.
When I send a request, I get an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error back.
Currently, I hardcoded the result of TokenValidationResult to be as forgiving as possible.
Do I need to change the code in any way?
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobar"))
        };

        options.TokenHandlers.Clear();
        options.TokenHandlers.Add(new MyJwtTokenHandler());

The JWT token handler:
public class MyJwtTokenHandler : TokenHandler
{
    public override Task<TokenValidationResult> ValidateTokenAsync(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new(
        [
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, "John Doe"),
            new(ClaimTypes.Email, "johndoe@gmail.com")
        ]);

        var result = new TokenValidationResult
        {
            IsValid = true,
            ClaimsIdentity = identity
        };

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}


The hard coding may be the issue.  Your token (cookie) may be expired and is failing.  You need to get a new cookie.   Using Postman may help you debug.  See if Postman works.  Postman may give better errors or add missing http header.  If Postman works than check Postman Control Panel and get the entire request which will show all the http headers.

Have you seen your token by decoding the values? Is the right claims and time available there?

In my test if without "SecurityToken", OnChallenge event will report a failure.

You could try following code works to implement from TokenHandler
    public class MyJwtTokenHandler : TokenHandler
    {
        public override  Task<TokenValidationResult> ValidateTokenAsync(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
        {

            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new(ClaimTypes.Name, "John Doe"),
                    new(ClaimTypes.Email, "johndoe@gmail.com")
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxx"));

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),           
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4)),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            var result = new TokenValidationResult
            {
                IsValid = true,
                SecurityToken = securityToken,
                ClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,"jwt"),            

            };
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }


Implemented your code and it works! Thanks!
The request gets authorized and the called API op is being called too now.
I will now go on and add some more sensical claims.

@ngruson Great to hear that. Just remind the "Expires" and "SigningCredentials" is not necessary in the tokenDescriptor.
